# quando o usuário cadastra seu produto vá direto para seu painel (php)

Tags: php

Tenho um sistema e nele quando o usuario cadastra vai direto pra página de anuncios, só que agora ele não lista o produto desse usuario no painel dele

```
<?php
include_once ("../Model/Produto.php");

if (isset($_REQUEST)){
    $action = $_REQUEST['action'];
} else {
    $action = "";
}

$Produto = new Produto;

switch ($action){

    case 'listar':
        $listaProdutos = $Produto->listar();
        $listaProdutosComprar = $Produto->listarCompra();
        $listaProdutosDoacao = $Produto->listarDoacao();
        $listaProdutosCruzar = $Produto->listarCruzar();
        include_once '../View/listarProduto.php';
        include_once '..View/painel.php';
        break;
}
```

Comment: Ele não lista o produto que acabou de ser cadastrado ou todos os produtos? Se for a primeira opção, é provável que o model esteja obtendo os dados do banco antes de devidamente fazer o cadastro.

Comment: Bem primeiro ele cadastra no banco e depois vamos dizer que ele faz uma listagem de todos os produtos como se fosse anuncios.

Comment: não ta faltando a `/` ali no include antes do break `..View/Painel.php`, não seria `../View/Painel.php`?